# Output for arranging elements in NonDecreasing Order do not come as Expected?

Tags: java, sorting

> Chandu's girlfriend loves arrays that are sorted in non-increasing order. Today is her birthday. Chandu wants to give her some sorted arrays on her birthday. But the shop has only unsorted arrays. So, Chandu bought T unsorted arrays and is trying to sort them. But, he doesn't have much time to sort the arrays manually as he is getting late for the birthday party. So, he asked you to write a program to sort the T arrays in non-increasing order. Help him, or his girlfriend will kill him.

Input:

First line contains an integer T, denoting the number of test cases.
First line of each test case contains an integer N, denoting the size of the array.
Second line contains N space separated integers, denoting the array elements Ai.

Output:

For each test case, print the sorted array in non-increasing order.

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= N <= 105
0 <= Ai <= 109
```

**MYApproach**

My first approach is to code the solution using simple approach.For this,I tried BubbleSort Algorithm.But in the last TestCase,I am not getting Expected Output.I Used bubble sort to sort the elements which compares adjacent element for every iteration of k in sort loop.Thus,The smallest element will go at the end

> Can anyone guide me Why?

Below is the Code:

```
 public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception 
 {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     int T=sc.nextInt();//Take the int Input from user
     sc.nextLine(); //to move to nextLine after consuming token
     int NoOfElements=sc.nextInt();
     sc.nextLine();//to move to nextLine
     int x[]=new int[NoOfElements];
     for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
     {
        for(int j=0;j<NoOfElements;j++)
        {
             x[j]=sc.nextInt();

        }
        sort(x);
     }

 }
 public static void sort(int p[])
 {

    for(int k=0;k<p.length-1;k++)
    {
        //bubble sort
        for(int i=0;i<p.length-k-1;i++)
        {
            if(p[i]<p[i+1])
            {
                //swap
                int temp=p[i];
                p[i]=p[i+1];
                p[i+1]=temp;

            }

        }
    }       
        for(int m=0;m<p.length;m++)
        {
            System.out.print(p[m]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
          System.out.println();



  }
 }

  Input
 2
 5
 2 5 2 4 3 
 5
 5 4 2 3 1

 My Code's Output
 5 4 3 2 2 
 5 5 4 3 2 //Why I am getting 5 here.I could not correct it.

 Expected Correct Output
 5 4 3 2 2
 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading the number of elements once. Not once per test case.

Below I have updated your code to read the `NoOfElements` once for each test case and allocate an array there as well.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    int T = sc.nextInt(); //Take the int Input from user
    sc.nextLine(); //to move to nextLine after consuming token

    for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {
        int NoOfElements = sc.nextInt(); // THIS LINE MOVED INTO LOOP
        sc.nextLine();                   // THIS LINE MOVED INTO LOOP
        int x[] = new int[NoOfElements];
        for (int j = 0; j < NoOfElements; j++) {
            x[j] = sc.nextInt();

        }
        sort(x);
    }

 }
```